# Generate certs in Java for proxy root ca without dependency on OpenSSL?

Tags: java, ssl, proxy

I've searched for this for months on StackOverflow and on multiple other forums and I didn't know what else to do. I know questions have been asked that are similar but whenever I try to code from these or try implementing it from other sources it always fails, so please please please can you help me with what am I missing?

We are migrating to Windows from Linux and I can't figure out a way to run openssl, so looking at BouncyCastle and JavaKeyTool functions seems to be the way to go, I'm open to suggestions though. We need the root certificate to stay the same, it's already on 100's of PC's, this is generating certificates on the fly for a mitm proxy that's used to help vulnerable people, it's for a good cause. (I've tried looking at LittleProxy on GitHub too and I still can't get it to work).

My current program is:

```
// Generate key
Functions.RunInTerminal("sudo openssl genrsa -out ./ssl_ca_gen/private/" + filename + ".key 1024");
// Create CSR
Functions.RunInTerminal("sudo openssl req -new -config ./ssl_ca_gen/conf/openssl_cust_tmp" + tmp_ext + ".cnf -out ./ssl_ca_gen/" + filename + ".csr -key ./ssl_ca_gen/private/" + filename + ".key -subj \"/C=US/ST=SOMESTATE/L=SOMECITY/O=OURCOMPANYNAME/OU=OURUNIT/CN=" + domain + "\" ");
// Sign CSR
Functions.RunInTerminal("sudo openssl ca -batch -config ./ssl_ca_gen/conf/openssl_ca_tmp" + tmp_ext + ".cnf -in ./ssl_ca_gen/" + filename + ".csr -out ./ssl_ca_gen/" + filename + ".crt -extensions v3_req -extfile ./ssl_ca_gen/conf/openssl_ca_tmp" + tmp_ext + ".cnf");
// Convert cert
Functions.RunInTerminal("sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -in ./ssl_ca_gen/" + filename + ".crt -inkey ./ssl_ca_gen/private/" + filename + ".key -certfile ./ssl_ca_gen/public/root.pem > ./ssl_ca_gen/" + filename + ".p12 -passin pass:" + password + " -passout pass:" + password + "");
// Import into keystore
Functions.RunInTerminal("keytool -importkeystore -noprompt -srckeystore ./ssl_ca_gen/" + filename + ".p12 -destkeystore ./ssl_ca_gen/serverkeys_" + filename + " -srcstorepass " + password + " -deststorepass " + password + " -srcstoretype pkcs12");
```

Extra things that might help:

```
String filename = domain.replaceAll("\\.", "_");
if (renew || !new File("./ssl_ca_gen/serverkeys_" + filename).exists()) {
    // Check index and serial exist
    if (!new File("./ssl_ca_gen/conf/serial").exists()) {
        Functions.RunInTerminal("echo \"01\" > ./ssl_ca_gen/conf/serial");
        Functions.RunInTerminal("touch ./ssl_ca_gen/conf/index");
    }

    // Create temp ca_conf
    String ca_temp = TextFile.ReadAll("./ssl_ca_gen/conf/openssl_ca.cnf", "\n");
    ca_temp = ca_temp.replaceAll("%domain%", domain);
    String tmp = "./ssl_ca_gen/conf/openssl_ca_tmp" + tmp_ext + ".cnf";
    TextFile.QuickWrite(tmp, ca_temp);

    if (!new File(tmp).exists()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create file " + tmp);
    }

    // Create temp cust_conf
    String cust_temp = TextFile.ReadAll("./ssl_ca_gen/conf/openssl_cust.cnf", "\n");
    cust_temp = cust_temp.replaceAll("%password%", password);
    cust_temp = cust_temp.replaceAll("%domain%", domain);
    TextFile.QuickWrite("./ssl_ca_gen/conf/openssl_cust_tmp" + tmp_ext + ".cnf", cust_temp);

    // INSERT CURRENT PROGRAM (^ Functions.RunInTerminal("sudo... etc ^)
}
```

We can still run the keytool on the new class that I'm writing by using a nativeCall:

```
private static String nativeCall(final String... commands) {
    Logger.info("Running '" + Arrays.asList(commands) + "'");
    final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    try {
        final Process process = pb.start();
        final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

        byte[] data = ByteStreams.toByteArray(is);
        String dataAsString = new String(data);

        Logger.info("Completed native call: '" + Arrays.asList(commands) + "'");
        Logger.info("Response: '" + dataAsString + "'");
        return dataAsString;
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        Logger.error("Error running commands: " + Arrays.asList(commands));
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? What problem does removing the dependency on OpenSSL solve?

Comment: We used to use Linux for development, but we're migrating to Windows for our PC's and Servers, so it's to make the certificate generating process OS independent. All of the RunInTerminal parts of our proxy will be getting removed. @EJP

Comment: OpenSSL is available on Windows, and already installed with a lot of the software you will already be using. Java by itself cannot sign certificates. You will have to add a dependency in BouncyCastle or similar.

Comment: Thank you @EJP, your effort to try and help is really appreciated. I've already installed OpenSSL on my Windows Machine, but how would I call that from the java code? My RunInTerminal method was built for Linux by someone that has left the company. Using nativeCall doesn't see OpenSSL even after I've added it to PATH and this still doesn't work? I have BouncyCastle in the dependencies, I've tried to use this multiple times and can't get it to use the existing root.pem certificate authority, so all the websites display a security issue in the browser still. Thanks, Kai.